# How full translate a word with python?

Tags: python, google-translate

I have written a program that opens a file and translates it word by word, but it has a big problem, and that is that it only gives one type of meaning. I want to make it return the meaning of the word according to the sentence for For example, show the meaning of the word <**Season**> according to the following sentences. Example:

1. My favorite season is winter.
2. The recipe says to season the dish with plenty of salt.

I used the following codes also want to display the pronunciation of the word

season /ˈsiː.zən/

```
from googletrans import Translator
g = Translator()

def tr(ch):
    return(g.translate(ch,'fa').text)
```

I searched many sites but could not find the answer

Comment: If you're doing this word by word, then you can't avoid this, because the translator doesn't HAVE the context. Even a human translator would have the same problem.

Comment: The google translate app gets the translations correct given the whole sentences which obviously provide the context for **season**

Comment: What I want to do is to first give the sentence to the translator and then determine the meaning of a word in the sentence that corresponds to which word or words from the translated text?

Comment: What should I do to pronounce the words? season /ˈsiː.zən/